# AMP-Story , Dynamic Bookend.json

Tags: php, amp-html

i want to create this dynamically

```
"related-articles": {
"Articles": [
  {
    "title": "Pet adoption",
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pet_adoption",
    "image": "/assets/related-dogs.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "Learn about cats",
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat",
    "image": "/assets/related-cats.jpg"
  }
]
```

}

which is helpful for create amp-story bookend.json

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: core php i am using

Comment: You could create an associative array in php with the json formatting and use `json_enconde` ([documented here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php))

Comment: This is more of a PHP question than an AMP question; see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=build+json+php for other questions like this, but generally graciano's answer applies